# Can we merge two memory mapped files?

Tags: c#, memory-mapped-files

Can we merge two memory mapped files? if so the how? if not then why not?

Comment: Can you describe in a few more words, preferibly with sample code what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: What do you mean by "merge"? Memory-mapping a file is just another way of looking at the data in the file. Can you describe your desired result without using memory mapping?

Comment: You cannot *merge* two mmap'ed regions, but you can *copy* the data from one to the other or create a unified *view*.

Comment: I just want to write one memory mapped file data into another memory mapped file. For example, I have one MMF that has "Hello" written into it and have another file that has "World" written into. Now I want to write second MMF file data into first MMF file to make it "Hello World".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here are my first experiences with [`MemoryMappedFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile.aspx), give it a try:

```
String f1Path = @"C:\Temp\Test1.txt";
String f2Path = @"C:\Temp\Test2.txt";
byte[] buffer;
int offset;
int length;

using (FileStream f1ReadStream = new FileStream(f1Path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    offset = (int)f1ReadStream.Length;
}
using (FileStream f2ReadStream = new FileStream(f2Path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    length = (int)f2ReadStream.Length;
}
// read file2 and append all to file1
using (var mappedFile2 = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(f2Path, FileMode.Open, null,  length))
{
    using (var reader = mappedFile2.CreateViewStream(0, length, MemoryMappedFileAccess.Read))
    {
        // Read from MMF
        buffer = new byte[length];
        reader.Read(buffer, 0, length);
    }
}

using (var mappedFile1 = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(f1Path,FileMode.Open, null, offset + length))
{
    // Create writer to MMF
    using (var writer = mappedFile1.CreateViewAccessor(offset, length, MemoryMappedFileAccess.Write))
    {
        // Write to MMF
        writer.WriteArray<byte>(0, buffer, 0, length);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great!!..Seems to be working. Need to check if it suits to my scenario. Thanks that you devoted your time.

Comment: can you please answer my question ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9760073/memorymappedfile-doesnt-work-with-2-processes

Comment: It doesn't work in my project. I don't know why. Test1.txt doesn't change.