# Use MemoryMappedViewAccessor to write to memory-mapped file?

Tags: c#, io, memory-mapped-files, memory-mapping

I want to write data to Memory Mapped File. actually, I want to save it after changes on the disk. Is it possible? I've searched the internet, but I've only found that if I call Write() the other processes that use this MMF will see the changes. how to save it?

I am using

```
var mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile("test", FileMode.Open, "myFile");
var mmfa = mmf.CreateViewAccessor(0, 10);
byte a = 0;
mmfa.Write(0, a);
```

but the file on the disk doesn't change.

Comment: It is impossible to *not* save it if you actually passed a file handle to CreateFileMapping().  What are you talking about?

Comment: I have only few experiences with MMF but have a look my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9634007/284240 It might be helpful since i'm writing with a [`MemoryMappedViewAccessor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedviewaccessor.aspx).

Comment: i call : `var mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile("test", FileMode.Open, "myFile");var mmfa = mmf.CreateViewAccessor(0, 10);
            byte a = 0;
            mmfa.Write(0, a);`. but file on the disk doesn't change

Comment: @TimSchmelter: i've tried what you advised but nothing happens. i can't change the file.

Comment: @VasiliiRuzov I have never used MMVA, but what happens if using [`Flush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedviewaccessor.aspx)?